# Determining Context free language

Tags: automata

Problem: Define for the context free language

```
L< {0,1} init (L) =  { u | u v ε L for some v in {0, 1}}
If L { w | w is nonempty and has an equal number of 0's and 1's}, 
then init (L) is set of all binary strings?
```

Answer:

```
 init (L) is set of all binary strings including the null string
but how to prove it?
```

Comment: I believe this question is a better suit for the Computer Science community - http://cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

First I think you've missed a * in you definition of init(L):

```
...for some v in {0, 1}*}
```

And the proof:
If you have an arbitrary string u of 0's and 1's, you can concatenate it with another string, say v such that the total number of 0's and 1's in w=uv become equal (Simply add missing 0's or 1's to the end of u).
Hence any string in {0,1}* could be a prefix of L, therefore init(L)={0,1}*